# OpenSSL decrypt command with keyfile

Tags: openssl, aes

I have a file encrypted with OpenSSL. I'm trying to decrypt it with the password however password is in some characters that I can't enter by copy/paste.

Here is command I use.

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in video.ts -out output.ts -K (key) \
    -iv 18AD77B0FC9C1EB54C38767D4E3D3CB0W̕۶
```

My question is how can I use -K option for files? So OpenSSL will read the key from file instead of paste to the command directly which I can't do.

Comment: Did you try to use Edit command by right mouse click on the top border of command window?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer in a book. "kfile"

Comment: Looking back on this, don't you think this Q/A lacks a lot of quality?

Comment: This site is for programming questions only. Answers should contain at least a description on how the problem was solved. For command line usage you should go to superuser instead. So maybe *you* should [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) yourself.